# Как выбрать запись которой соответствует наибольшее значение в другой таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Пытаюсь реализовать запрос, в котором хочу вывести ФИО работника, который выполнил самое большое количество заказов (объектов).

Работаю с таким таблицами:

```
user (id_user,first_name,last_name ...), 

employee (id_employee,user_id,team_id), 

team(id_team,name),

team_object(id_team_object, id_team,id_object), 

object(id_object,address)
```

Каждый из работников, работает в команде, которая выполняет заказ (объект). Вот и не как не получается это реализовать таким образом, чтобы получилось вывести работника с самым большим количество выполненных работ (хочу использовать оператор ANY или ALL).

В моем примере проверяю, больше ли 10 сделал работник, а хочу, чтобы проверяло кто из них сделал самое большее заказов (это пока не получается реализовать).

```
select first_name,last_name from user1 s1
where user_id = any (
    select user_id from employee
    join team using(team_id)
    join team_object using (team_id)
    join object1 using (object_id)
    where s1.user_id = employee.user_id
    group by user_id
    having count(team_object_id) >10
```

Comment: если вам нужен максимум, то странно, что вы не используете функцию `max`

Comment: @teran У меня в мыслях была идея такая (но не пойму как-то ее реализовать) Просуммировать количество выполненных работ работниками и вывести максимальное (то есть кто выполнил самое большее работ или скорее принимал участие в работах)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with q as (
  select
  employee.user_id, count(team_object.id_team_object) as count
  from team_object
  join employee on employee.team_id = team_object.id_team
  group by employee.user_id
)
select first_name, last_name
from user
join q on q.user_id = user.id_user and q.count = (select max(count) from q)
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2938fb35ce06ea0ee612f2832be04798)

Comment: Благодарю, довольно элегантно сделано. У меня были мысли использовать `with` и подсчитать так, но как-то наверно не подумал об этом.

Comment: @JuniorLittle Вы бы добавили на фиддле пару записей тестовых данных (это ваша задача, не ответившего).

Comment: получилось прогнать на реальных данных? и, кстати, `employee` явно должен содержать в себе дату начала и окончания трудовой деятельности